# "?" printed instead of emoji

Tags: java, emoji

When coding the emojis, despite using utf-8s, it only outputs "?".

```
System.out.print(boyName + ", will you be my boyfriend? ");
String response = scanner.nextLine();

switch (response.toLowerCase()) 
{
    case "yes":
        System.out.println("Yay! \uD83D\uDE0A"); 
        break;
    case "maybe":
        System.out.println("I'll wait for your decision! \uD83E\uDD14");
        break;
    case "no":
        System.out.println("\uD83D\uDE22"); 
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("gulo mo, 3 na nga lang pagpipilian");
}
```

Comment: Unicode is one thing, font supporting these characters is another. Are you sure your does that?

Comment: Not sure how (or where) you are running this, but it works fine [here](https://i.imgur.com/bRSrn1i.png).

Comment: It will also depend on the 'console' you are using if it has the right encoding configuration. Are you testing on a terminal, in a tab inside Visual Code? Include that in the question because that's part of the reproduction steps you should share.

Comment: outputs where? ---

Comment: Thank you for the comments.

1. Yes I am running it on VSC's terminal.
2. The output is 

Choose char: boy
Type in name: [name]
[name], Will you be my boyfriend?
Yes
?